# Will a compiler discard a class implementation if not used in code?

Tags: templates, c++11, optimization, specialization

Probably the title is a bit misleading. But before I get to the actual question, let me explain the situation that I'm currently in.

I need to create several specializations of a class/structure to help me select the proper type depending on the specified template parameter. Here's a simplified example:

```
struct TypeA;
struct TypeB;
struct TypeC;

template < typename T > struct TypeSelector
{
    typedef DefaultType Type;
};

template <> struct TypeSelector< TypeA >
{
    typedef SuggestedForTypeA Type;
};

template <> struct TypeSelector< TypeB >
{
    typedef SuggestedForTypeB Type;
};

template <> struct TypeSelector< TypeC >
{
    typedef SuggestedForTypeC Type;
};
```

And I may end up doing several of these specializations that could even be nested.

At first, I looked if I could avoid such approach with the new c++11 keyword `using` (*out of curiosity*). But apparently, it can't be used to create specializations. So I'm left with this approach.

However, to my understanding, abusing this type of approach is not very good for the compiled code. As I end up creating a bunch of new types for every other types that I might be using with these specializations.

And I'm basically just using these types as a smarter `typedef` and not actually creating instances of them.

So my question is. Will a decent compiler see that I'm not using these types and discard them from the compiled code?

Or is there an attribute that I can specify to indicate such behavior?

Recent C++11/14/17 features are not an issue as I'm using MinGW/GCC 6.1.0

Comment: In the cases you supplied there is no class implementation to discard. If the classes were never instantiated the compiler wouldn't generate constructors, destructors, assignment operators, etc. either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is almost nothing for the compiler to actually instantiate in case of class templates in your example. There are no member functions, no static member data, etc. Aside from some type information for RTTI mechanisms, there is nothing that could take up space or performance at any stage during the execution of your program.

I am not aware of any portable way to tell the compiler to "please do not generate any kind of data for this class". However, if I were you, I would happily employ this practice, as it is already widely used in the STL in the form of type traits. The overhead of adding your class templates and their specializations will be negligible.